# Equality of functions in Haskell, syntax problems

Tags: haskell, syntax, functional-programming

I've been trying to implement an instance Eq for a Function but I keep getting Syntax erros and can't find anywhere how it's supposed to be. A function is equal if for every input it throws the same output. So I tried just going through every input and check if the results are equal.

```
newtype Funktion = Fkt { f :: Zahlraum_0_10 -> Zahlraum_0_10 }

data Zahlraum_0_10 = N | I | II | III | IV | V | VI
                     | VII | VIII | IX | X | F deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

instance Eq Funktion where
  (==) (Fkt f2 _) (Fkt f1 _) = f2 I == f1 I && f2 II == f1 II && f2 III == f1 III &&
  f2 IV == f1 IV && f2 V == f1 V && f2 VI == f1 VI && f2 VII == f1 VII && f2 VIII == f1 VIII &&
  f2 IX == f1 IX && f2 X == f1 X && f2 N == f1 N && f2 F == f1 F
```

Comment: Two problems: In your pattern matching, `Fkt` has only one argument but you match two. (Get rid of the underscores after `f2` and `f1`). Second: Indentation. Make sure the 3rd and 4th lines in your `Eq` declaration are indented a bit to the right. But more importantly, there are better ways to write what you want: Make your datatype instance of `Enum` and `Bounded`, and then you can just do `and [f1 x == f2 x | x <- [minBound .. maxBound]]`

Comment: @alias Right, but doesn't the list comprehension return a list of Bools? I want just a single Bool, right?

Comment: Note the call to `and` over the result. `and [...]`, which conjuncts all the bools.

Comment: @PramoxLol: list comprehension indeed returns a *list* of `Bool`s, but the `and` function will turn that into a single `Bool`: `True` if all `Bool`s in the list are `True` and `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is about the use of the `Fkt` data constructor: your `Fkt` data constructor has only *one* attribute: the function `f` that maps a `Zahlraum_0_10` to a `Zahlraum_0_10`. You thus unpack the function out of the `Fkt` with `Fkt f1`, so without a `_` as second attribute:

It might also be better to work with [**`all :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) since this reduce the amount of code (and makes it less error prone) to compare the two functions:

```
instance Eq Funktion where
  Fkt f1 == Fkt f2 = all go [N, I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X, F]
    where go x = f1 x == f2 x
```

We can also work with [**`liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2) instead of defining a `go` function:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

instance Eq Funktion where
  Fkt f1 == Fkt f2 = all (liftA2 (==) f1 f2) [N, I, II, III, IV, V, VI, VII, VIII, IX, X, F]
```

We do not have to define the list of values explicitly: since all the data constructors have no parameters, one can easily make these an instance of `Enum` and `Bounded`:

```
data Zahlraum_0_10 = N | I | II | III | IV | V | VI
                     | VII | VIII | IX | X | F deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)
```

In that case we can determine if the two functions map to the same value for each parameter with:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)

instance Eq Funktion where
  Fkt f1 == Fkt f2 = all (liftA2 (==) f1 f2) [minBound ..]
```